# scrapy and chromium tools don't return the same values

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy and am playing around with its shell at the moment. As a simple exercise, I would like to extract the visible room images from this site:
https://www.gumtree.com/flats-houses/london.
After firing off the shell:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.gumtree.com/flats-houses/london"
```

I'm using the following simple command which is supposed to do the job:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='listing-side']/div[@class='listing-thumbnail']/img/@src").extract()
```

But however it returns a 30 element list, 25 values of which are empty strings. First I thought there must have been something wrong with my xpath so I tested it with chromium tools and I must say it works like a charm returning a full list of image urls. Everything as expected. But why does scrapy not do the same then?

EDIT:

Oh sorry, actually in case of this site, to start the shell one has to issue the following command:

```
shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozila/5.0" "https://www.gumtree.com/flats-houses/london"
```

In other words, the user agent must be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
listings = response.xpath("//div[@class='listing-thumbnail']")
images = [listing.xpath('.//img/@src').extract()[1] for listing in listings]
```

'images' is a list with all listings images.

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't understand why my approach does not. Even though after playing around for some more time I figured out that if I change the "src" attribute to "data-lazy", it starts working as expected. And what should be noted here is that both methods work equally well with chromium tools. Do you have any ideas on how to explain this behaviour?

Comment: @Albert, before making any scraper you should make sure you disable javascript and then come up with the logic for scraping. Else you will get confused between browser and scrapy behavior.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Ah too right! For some reason I didn't think about it, my bad. But now everything is clear. Thank you!

Comment: @Albert please remember that Scrapy does not handle javascript by default. If you want to scrape websites with content generated by javascript, you can use Splash [link](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash)

Comment: @mostaszewski Yeah I'd say it's obvious and quite logical but for some reason it just slipped my mind...and I was like : "why in the name of all that's wonderful...". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No way. There is a solution for you. The way you expected. Try this:

```
for item in response.xpath("//img[@itemprop='image'][not(@aria-hidden)]/@src").extract():
    print(item)
```

And using css selector:

```
for item in response.css("[itemprop='image']:not([aria-hidden])::attr(src)").extract():
    print(item)
```